# SQL alternative to Cross apply

Tags: sql

I have a requirement where to bring in all the records from left table for every match in right table.
Sample query below. In the temp table #Dates_Test in below query i am bringing past 1 weeks dates.
For each record in employee if the Date in temp table(#Dates_Test) is between MvIn_DT and MvOut_Dt , i have to return 7 rows. I can achieve expected output using CROSS APPLY , I am looking for alternatives other than CROSS APPLY. Thanks in advance.

Dates_test Result set:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Query:

```
 SELECT c.Name 
  ,c.ID  
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) AS [ID_Count]  
   ,t2.DATE AS SvcDate  
 INTO #Test
 FROM Employee c  
 CROSS APPLY (  
  SELECT [Date]  
  FROM #Dates_Test t  
  WHERE t.DATE BETWEEN c.MvIn_DT  
    AND c.MvOut_DT
  ) t2  
 WHERE c.[State] = 'NY'
 GROUP BY t2.DATE  
  ,c.ID
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using cross apply?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

This would more normally be written using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.ID, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) AS [ID_Count], 
       t2.DATE AS SvcDate  
INTO #Test
FROM Employee c JOIN
     #Dates_Test t 
     ON t.DATE BETWEEN c.MvIn_DT AND c.MvOut_DT  
WHERE c.[State] = 'NY'
GROUP BY t2.DATE, c.Name, c.ID ;
```

But if you want an improvement in performance, these will probably be pretty similar.